# wordpress font css doesnt work in firefox

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox, fonts

I have added a custom font to my wordpress based website.
the theme has the font files within it.

so far in testing the new font works in chrome, IE and safari but not in firefox.

Ive tried playing about with my css files but no luck

any ideas why?

Comment: Which font file types are you using?

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is that Internet Explorer accepts only EOT fonts, while Firefox supports only OTF and TTF fonts, and so on.
plz try to insert all this king of font extentions

i hope this help you.

Comment: According to the OP the problem is with Firefox not IE.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a useful tool for having every extension for your fonts: [font2web.com](http://www.font2web.com)